# Ant task for generating ER diagram from JPA/Hibernate annotated classes

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, ant

Does anyone know of a tool that can do that?

[Linguine maps](http://www.softwaresecretweapons.com/jspwiki/linguinemapsforhibernate) seems to only work on old hibernate xml files. And the hibernate tool task hbm2hbmxml seems to have [a bug](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=992077&view=previous) so that I can't do the two step process "annotations->hbmxml->diagram"

Best,
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you're looking for but you could use [API Viz](http://code.google.com/p/apiviz/) which automatically produces UML like diagrams from class hierarchies and can be augmented with doclet tags.

You'd have to mark up your classes a little, but it's a great tool and worth using wherever you're trying to visualise large or complex projects.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I've found [this great post on developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ap06108/index.html). There the author seems to generate entity diagrams from a live database. I wonder if I can go "annotated classes -> live db (eg. H2) -> SchemasSpy generated diagram?

And yes, API Viz looks great.

I've [blogged my hacky solution with SchemaSpy](http://www.code3.dk/automated-documentation-and-odfdom/).