# ER diagram from Hibernate Entity classes

Tags: java, mysql, entity-framework, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

Is there any way or **any tool** or an **eclipse plugin** that **can generate ER (Entity-relationship) diagram from hibernate entity classes**???? Please note that **I don't want an ER diagram from database** What **I want is ER diagram from Entity classes** I am using MySQL database java6 Please Let me know I am in a desperate need.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: There's an ant task that might help, it's linked in the question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017997/ant-task-for-generating-er-diagram-from-jpa-hibernate-annotated-classes